# How do I link my '.lib' and '.dll' files in play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, lib

I have my project in play framework (scala). For this project, I have already loaded jar file into the lib direcctory of my project. I don't know where to place the '.lib' and '.dll' files. Now I have them inside the lib directory and the project shows the following error:

> RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no facesdk in java.library.path

Can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: See [this project](https://github.com/playframework/play-native-loader) and an [example here](https://github.com/playframework/play-native-loader/blob/master/src/main/java/play/libs/NativeLoader.java).

Comment: I have downloaded that project,please guide me where to put those files.I have added that dependency in the build.sbt and what to do  next?

Comment: I  have loaded that project you mentioned to the eclipse and referenced the NativeLoader.java in my project,but still the problem exists :-(

Comment: You can add the native libraries inside the `lib` folder.

Comment: I have them in lib directory but the error still exists!!

Comment: Well, we need to see some code. Create a small simple project that reproduces the problem.

Comment: In the homeController I inserted the loadLibrary method :                      
  `def cap1 = Action{
    System.loadLibrary("facesdk")
    var e1 = new Define
    Ok(views.html.welcome(e1.scan))
  }`

Comment: @marcospereira can you please specify a permanent solution for this....?:-/

Answer (score 0):

Is the .so / dll really in  java.library.path ? If yes, are it's dependencies also present ?

Youn need to check where java.library.path points to, and make sure the OS is able to load the .so / dll and all of it's dependencies.

Comment: How to check whether the dll is in the java.library.path or not??.If not then how to load them??